# NavMesh.SamplePosition() fails after rebaking NavMesh?

Tags: unity, rotation, navmesh

So today I was refurbishing a scene when this happened. After baking a new Navmesh the SamplePosition() returned only infinity. I tried a lot of things out but eventually went back to an older version of my project. Sooner or later I will have to bake a new Navmesh though, so I'd really like to know what happened there.

Here is the part of the code that appears to cause trouble:

```
Vector3 randomDirection = Random.insideUnitSphere * roamRadius;
NavMeshHit hit;
NavMesh.SamplePosition(randomDirection, out hit, roamRadius, 1);
direction = hit.position;
```

And of course this, since it tries  to look into infinity I suppose:

```
transform.LookAt(transform.position - direction, Vector3.up);
```

Again, this code works fine. Only after baking a Navmesh this fails horribly.

Answer (score 1):

Better later than never with an answer: 5.3.5 here, I had the same issue.
The solution was to "bake" (got the joke?) the last parameter for `SamplePosition()` to "1". Everything else fails.

I tried:
`NavMesh.GetAreaFromName([anything])` **FAIL**
`NavMesh.AllAreas` **FAIL**
`1 << NavMesh.GetNavMeshLayerFromName("Default")` (from an old post, also tried with "Walkable" and without shifting) **FAIL**, etc.
The only thing worked was this:
`NavMesh.SamplePosition(transform.position, out nHit, 0.1f, 1);`
(The distance parameter -*0.1f in the example*- can be anything, that param actually works...).
Hope this helps! If too late for an answer, well, hope it saves a few hours for a random visitor! :)
Cheers!